# Django - after login using google, i tried to access a simple api view. gives Unauthorized error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

my view

```
class ldata(APIView):

def get(self, request):

    data = "my name"
    return Response(data)
```

i can confirm, every time i login using google, it successfully register the user to auth_user & social_auth_usersocialauth table.

but i am getting this error when i access the view.

```
{
 "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

i have configured everything said here https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

and added few code to settings for google login

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
# for Google authentication
'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = "***"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = "***"
```

my login call url: http://localhost:8000/auth/login/google-oauth2/

eidts:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
),

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
}
```

Comment: what information did you give the `REST_FRAMEWORK` in your settings.py?

Comment: i have added my REST_FRAMEWORK details in the post bottom

Comment: I think this post https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/65 might be able to help you out. Because it's rather weird that if you followed their tutorial of how to install it that it still gives that error.